# Is it necessary to call response.end() on every connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using SSE, so the only methods needed are response.writeHead and response.write since the response never really ends. The only way it will end is by client diconnecting and this brings me to my question ...

Do I need to listen to "close" event and manually call response.end or it makes no difference? Technically the connection is gone already anyway, so the response cannot be flushed or anything. Therefore I am confused whether the nodejs will properly unload everything even if response.end was never called for a specific response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting up a connection for SSE, you just set the headers and then call `res.write()` whenever you want to send data.  Keep in mind that you need to send some sort of delimiters (such as a line break) so that the client knows when it has received a "chunk" of data that it can process.

Here are a couple examples of nodejs and server sent events and you can see that it just uses `res.write()` whenever it wants to send data:

https://jasonbutz.info/2018/08/server-sent-events-with-node

https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/express/server-sent-events

> Do I need to listen to "close" event and manually call response.end or it makes no difference?

You do need to listen for the close if you have resources or timers on your end that you need to clean up when the connection is done (as you will see in some of the examples above).  You do not need to call `res.end()` when the connection closes as it's already been closed by the client.

Comment: Thanks. My question was more from nodejs process standpoint. Will it properly unload everything and garbage collect? The docs say that res.end() "...MUST be called on each response." Does that mean only when the nodejs is the one ending the response or in every case (even if the client closed connection and "close" was called)? Considering that "close" event is called, the process must be aware that the connection was closed, but I just want to make sure, so I won't discover that there was a memory leak or something after some time.

Comment: @sergiz - When the close event is received by the server, that means the socket is now closed.  There's nothing else for the server to do with that socket.  ``res.end()` is about completing a normal response when the socket is still open and waiting to be finished and then closed by the server.